# Create a function that checks if a number n is divisible by two numbers x AND y. All inputs are positive, non-zero digits

Tags: python

```
def is_divisible(n,x,y):
    #your code here
    n = int(input())
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    if n % x == 0 and y % x == 0:
            return True
    elif n % x != 0 and y % x != 0:
        return False
       
    
result = is_divisible(n=int(input()),x=int(input()),y=int(input()))
print(result)
```

Comment: why provide n,x,y to the function AND input it in the function again? this is essentially a `return n%x == 0 and n%y == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have an `elif`? The opposite of "being divisible by each of two numbers" is not "not being divisible by *either*", but "not being divisible by both *at the same time*". A simple `else` will do:

```
def is_divisible(n, x, y):
    if n % x == 0 and n % y == 0:  # use n both times!
        return True
    else:  # this case is: n % x != 0 OR n % y != 0
        return False
```

Or in short:

```
def is_divisible(n, x, y):
    return n % x == n % y == 0
```

Also note that you are already passing user input to the function. No need to do it again.